# Error in pinging localhost although have internet

Tags: networking, command-line, ping

i am working with my laptop lenovo think pad Edge.

i don't have any problem with internet, my internet is ADSL and i have an access point and connect to it with out any problem.

but when i run CMD as administrator and run command "Ping 127.0.0.1" or "Ping localhost" receive request timed out.

i don't have anti virus and my firewall is off.

i am a programmer and now work on read and write at SQL server from android devise and this problem not alow me to find best way to do this ?

how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please share your routing table ?

Comment: where is it? i don't know it.

Comment: "netstat -rn" or "route print" works in Windows 7

Comment: this is it's link [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=161xmjk&s=6)

Comment: Do you have any actual problem or is this just cosmetic?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your hosts. file in windows for below line:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

you can find your hosts file from:

```
 %windir%\system32\drivers\etc
```

add this if there is no such a line in that file add it and let me know.

and take a look at [how-to-edit-the-hosts-in-windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/145429/how-to-edit-the-hosts-in-windows-7)

Comment: yes, i checked it and sure that this line exists. when i run command "Ping 127.0.0.1" on CMD from 4 packages 1-3 packages get timed out.